# Specify CSS when nth-child() changes between pages

Tags: html, css, r, apply, rvest

I am having trouble specifying the correct CSS path when scraping multiple HTML elements. The problem is that the pages have slightly different set-ups so the element specified by `nth-child(#)` is out by 1 between the different pages. That is the element I am interested in 'Unit Code' is at `nth-child(20)` on some pages and `nth-child(21)` on others.

I will be running this over hundreds of sites so I need to figure out how to deal with this change in location. This code runs with `nth-child(21)` and predictably returns the incorrect text for the second URL.

I am using the package `rvest`.

```
library(rvest)
urls <- data.frame('site' = 1:2, 'urls' = c('https://www.deakin.edu.au/current-students/unitguides/UnitGuide.php?year=2015&semester=TRI-1&unit=SLE010',
                        'https://www.deakin.edu.au/current-students/unitguides/UnitGuide.php?year=2015&semester=TRI-2&unit=SLE339'))

urls$urls <- as.character(urls$urls)

uCode<- sapply(1:length(urls[,1]), function(x)
               html(urls[x,2]) %>% 
               html_nodes(css='#wmt_content > div:nth-child(21) > p.STANDARD') %>% 
               html_text())
```

The html for each of the pages is quite large and the pages are found at [first](https://www.deakin.edu.au/current-students/unitguides/UnitGuide.php?year=2015&semester=TRI-1&unit=SLE010) and [second](https://www.deakin.edu.au/current-students/unitguides/UnitGuide.php?year=2015&semester=TRI-2&unit=SLE339). The HTML containing the unit code, plus a couple of extra divs, looks like this:

```
 <div class="UnitGuideElementItem">
    <a name="0-UNIT-CODE"></a>
    <p style="font-size: 100%;" class="BOLD">
        "Unit code"
        <br>
        "&nbsp;"
        <br>
    <p style="font-size: 100%" class="STANDARD">
        "SLE334"
        <br>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="UnitGuideElementItem">
    <a name="0-UNIT-TITLE"></a>
    <p style="font-size: 100%;" class="BOLD">
       "Unit title"
       <br>
       "&nbsp;"
       <br>
    <p style="font-size: 100%" class="STANDARD">
       "Medical Microbiology and Immunology"
        <br>
  </div>
  <div class="UnitGuideElementItem">
     <a name="0-CONTACT-HOURS"></a>
     <p style="font-size: 100%;" class="BOLD">
        "Contact hours"
        <br>
        "&nbsp;"
        <br>
     <p style="font-size: 100%" class="STANDARD">
        "3 x 1 hour class per week, 5 x 3 hour practicals per trimester."
     <br>
  </div>
```

There is nothing unique about this section of HTML code compared with other sections except the `0-UNIT-CODE`in the `<a>` tag. By looking at a [w3schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/trysel.asp) I am able to get to the `<a>` tag, but can't figure out how to specify the `<p>` siblings within this node. Getting to the `<a>` tag:

```
uCode<- sapply(1:length(urls[,1]), function(x)
               html(urls[x,2]) %>% 
               html_nodes(css='[name$=CODE]') %>% 
               html_text())
```

Does anyone know how I might select the 'same' element, e.g. siblings of name="0-UNIT-CODE", from an HTML file when the elements location changes from page to page? Or, how do you return information from tags that you can only locate from a different tag type with the same parent?

EDIT: Included package name. Included link to sites and included more of the HTML for clarification.

Comment: Can't you assign a class?

Comment: It is generally good practice to indicate which package you are using if it's non-base, i.e. `rvest` in your case.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I can but that class is held by many other elements in the html so I end up getting a list of 39 values returned. I used, `css='.STANDARD'` and again can't figure out how to restrict it to the node that contains < a name='0-UNIT-CODE'>

Comment: In CSS, you can use the `+` combinator to select siblings that follow certain elements. e.g. in the HTML you posted, `.UnitGuideElementItem a + p` would select the `.BOLD` class, but not the `.STANDARD` class.

Comment: @TylerH thanks Tyler, would that also find all instances of `UnitGuideElementItem`? The problem is almost every < div > tag in the html is has the same class so I would end up selecting lots of information I am not interested in.

Comment: Is matching on an exact name "0-UNIT-CODE" OK, or must it be "ending with CODE" ?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee matching on the exact name "0-UNIT-CODE" would be perfect.

Comment: @Adam Yes, that would match all instances of `.UnitGuideElementItem`. It might be possible to just match the first instance on each page with `.UnitGuideElementItem:nth-of-type(1)` or `.UnitGuideElementItem:first-child`, but we really would need to see a bit more HTML to know for sure that we aren't selecting extra stuff that we don't want.

Comment: @TylerH sorry Tyler, I included the url in the code but probably should have specified it specifically. The html is rather large and I thought it would be a bit too much to post it all in the question. Would you recommend I include more in the question or point people to the url directly so they can check the full html from the page? url is https://www.deakin.edu.au/current-students/unitguides/UnitGuide.php?year=2015&semester=TRI-1&unit=SLE010

Comment: @Adam If there's tons of it, definitely include a link, but maybe an extra `<div>` or two would help illustrate the problem with the code, in case the site goes down some day (and someone else with the same problem happens upon this question). I'll take a look at that site now.

Comment: @Adam Is there is only one `.UnitGuideElementItem` that contains an `<a name="0-UNIT-Code">` per page? If so, you can use `.UnitGuideElementItem a[name$="CODE"] ~ p {}` to select all the siblings of the `<a>` element. You don't even *need* the `.UnitGuideElementItem` class, unless you have an anchor with the same name attribute elsewhere on the page.

Comment: @TylerH thanks, I added a little more info to the question to clarify... Yes, it seems that the `<a name=XXX>` is the only unique component for most of the nodes on the page. I will try your suggestion out, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xpath`'s "following-sibling": "find `<p class=STANDARD>` that is a sibling of and following the `<a name=0-UNIT-CODE>`.

```
uCode<- sapply(1:length(urls[,1]), function(x)
               html(urls[x,2]) %>% 
               html_nodes(xpath="//a[@name='0-UNIT-CODE']/following-sibling::p[@class='STANDARD']") %>% 
               html_text())
```

- `//a[@name='0-UNIT-CODE']` finds `<a>` with `name="0-UNIT-CODE"` (note: I think usually in xpath you do `//a[local-name()='0-UNIT-CODE']` but this syntax doesn't seem to be understood in this function?)
- the `/following-sibling::p[@class='STANDARD']` selects the following sibling of the `a` with class STANDARD.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I just have one question, is there a reason you used xpath rather than css? Do you see an advantage in learning one over the other? I am just getting into this stuff so am trying to figure out which I should focus on understanding first, xpath or css. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: @Adam XPath is a little more versatile in its ability to select things than CSS, but gets updated way less frequently (about once every 7 years), and it also relies on well-formed HTML5 or XHTML pages to be fully reliable in some edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you really want to select. I think you want all p elements after the given anchor:

```
a[name="0-UNIT-CODE"] ~ p {
   /* selects all siblings of type p after the first anchor with name attribute set to "0-UNIT-CODE" */
}
```

Comment: Because you need the selector but i gave you a rule set :)